# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property top of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code always gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Can you help me to solve this? Here's my code:

```
function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.header-body a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.header-body a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        } else {
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

here's the html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <title>GPL Spring 2017</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ URL::asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/main.css') }}" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/parallax.min.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/jquery.scrollto.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/main.js') }}"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header-body">
                <a class="menu active" href="#container1">HOME</a>
                <a class="menu" href="#container2">TICKETS</a>
                <a class="menu" href="javascript:void(0)">EVENTS</a>
                <a class="menu" href="javascript:void(0)">TEAM STANDINGS</a>
                <a class="menu" href="javascript:void(0)">ARTICLES</a>
                <a class="menu" href="javascript:void(0)">LIVE STREAM</a>
            </div>
        </header>
    <div id="container1" class="parallax-container" data-parallax="scroll" data-position="top" data-bleed="10" data-image-src="{{ URL::asset('/images/content1.png') }}" data-natural-width="1350" data-natural-height="1093">
    <div class="content1-page">
        <img class="fade-in" src="{{ URL::asset('/images/logo.png') }}" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="event-title">
            GARENA PREMIER LEAGUE SPRING 2017
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="date-title">
            APRIL 12 - 16
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="location-title">
            LIVE EVENT: SAMSUNG HALL
        </div>
        <div id="demo"></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="arrow" href="#container2"><img src="{{ URL::asset('/images/icon-arrow-dwn.png') }}" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<section>
    <div id="container2" class="container-ticket">
        <div class="content2-page">
            <div class="ticket-title">
                TICKETS
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="ticket-body">
                <div class="ticket-content1">
                    <div class="ticket-text">
                        <p>
                            I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It’s easy. Just click “Edit Text” or double click me to add your own content and make changes to the font. Feel free to drag and drop me anywhere you like on your page. I’m a great place for you to tell a story and let your users know a little more about you.​
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It’s easy. Just click “Edit Text” or double click me to add your own content and make changes to the font. Feel free to drag and drop me anywhere you like on your page. I’m a great place for you to tell a story and let your users know a little more about you.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tck-inc" onclick="inc()" class="ticket-btn-active">
                        Ticket Inclusions
                    </div>
                    <div id="tck-out" class="ticket-btn">
                        Ticket Outlets
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ticket-content2">
                    <div class="inclus">
                        <p>
                            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@include('footer')
```

sorry if posted it without the html code

Comment: The selector you're using to define the `refElement` is not finding anything. We can't offer any more help than that without seeing the relevant HTML

Comment: You've set `refElement` to a string (href). There is no position() method on a string and so on..

Comment: @dschu no it isn't. It's set to a jQuery object.

Comment: Try doing `console.log(currLink.attr("href"))` so see what is in the attribute - it should be a valid CSS selector.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Check out `$('.question-hyperlink:first').attr('href')`. It is returning a string. He then uses this string as a selector, which I bet, returns an empty object or null or something.

Comment: @dschu yes, but that's not what the OPs code is doing. Read it again

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You should read my comment again, or check my answer.

Comment: My reply was obviously to your original unedited comment. jQuery objects never return null, however if they do not contain any elements then the `position()` property will be null - hence the error.

Comment: I wonder what he's trying to accomplish. Why is he not using just `$(this).position()...`?

Comment: Thanks for the help... hmm.. just edited my post... every time i scroll the error is always showed up... just want to get rid of it...

Comment: Only the first (`HOME`) and the second (`TICKETS`) links that actually have a valid CSS selector as `href` value. The rest have `javascript:void(0)` which is invalid and thus nothing is selected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since not all of your links have their href value as a valid CSS selectors, you'll have to check if something is selected before accessing the `position`. Try this:

```
$('.header-body a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));

    if(!refElement.length) return;  // if the length is 0 (nothing selected) skip the rest of this iteration where the accessing of the position happens

    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('.header-body a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

position() returns `undefined`, therefore there is no "top" property.
Answer: Your selector is causing the error.

To fix this, you could test if `refElement.position()` is true, or not  `undefined`

Check this out:

```
$('woobaloobadubdub')
Returns: []

$('woobaloobadubdub').position()
Returns: undefined

$('woobaloobadubdub').position().top
Returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined(…)
```

Comment: `$('woobaloobadubdub')` returns `{..., length: 0}` not `[]`.